# Meteor: Show Loading Animation/Img/Template While App Is Downloading

Tags: meteor

My question is simple:
Is there a way to show some sort of loading animation while the page is loading (while the app is being downloaded onto the client)?

Update:
Basically, can I show a loading animation while it says "Wating for www.yoursite.com"

Comment: Do you use iron router? They have some nice hooks for this. If not there are other ways to basically show progress bars until collections are ready and etc but it depends on what you are loading. Are you loading images? Data? I think for a proper answer we need more information about your app.

Comment: @meteorDan Yes. I use iron router, but doesn't that take effect after the app is downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at my package which is doing exactly what Serkan mentioned.

only thing you have to do is to install it

`meteor add webdeb:app-loader`

Just deployed it 10min ago ;)
You question inspired me to write it, thanks!

github:
https://github.com/dropfen/meteor-app-loader/

Comment: This is an awesome package! Maybe for an update a config in which you can choose a certain gif as the loading animation would be really cool!

Comment: Also, could you upload it to github? I would love to take a look at the code.

Comment: added github link.. adding more loaders would be really cool!

Answer (score 1):

The [meteorhacks:inject-initial](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/inject-initial) package is created exactly for this purpose.

```
Inject.rawBody(id, textOrFunc, [res]). text
```

injects some html into the initial body of the html that is sent to the client. The client later on handles the rest.